# Class does not receive parameters sent by a service. Symfony2

Tags: symfony, service

I have a couple of days something lost with the **declaration of services**, especially when **passing parameters to custom classes**.

I have several extensions and listeners declared as **services**, to which I pass parameters to the constructor and **operating properly** but do the same for a custom class and does not work.

The error is that the class does **not receive parameters in the constructor**.

Error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Consolidador\PanelBundle\Controller\Integration::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry, none given, called in /var/www/vhosts/consolidadordeviajes.com/httpdocs/src/Consolidador/PanelBundle/Controller/HotelsController.php on line 149 and defined
```

This is the service that stated in `app/config/services.yml`:

```
integration:
        class: Consolidador\PanelBundle\Controller\Integration
        arguments: ['@doctrine', '@session']
```

This is the custom class:

```
<?php

namespace Consolidador\PanelBundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class Integration
{
    private $em;
    private $session;
            
    public function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine, Session $session)
    {
        $this->em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    ...
```

When I call the custom class is when the error occurs, I think I'm stating the service and collecting the parameters correctly, if not, I hope that other eyes may see the error that I get not find.

**A greeting and thanks.**

## SOLUTION

The problem was simply that instead of calling the custom class from e lcontendor dependency, trying instalanciarla manually. Now I know that the services have to call them:

```
$foo= $this->get('service_name');
$foo-Method();
```

Comment: Reading the error message it looks like you're instantiating your class manually instead of fetching it from the container.

Comment: How do you exactly call integration service in  `Consolidador/PanelBundle/Controller/HotelsController.php` on line 149?

Comment: Yes, I'm instance class manually, Is that not possible? Do I have to call it from the container dependencies? thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to get Integration instance from service container in `HotelsController` like this `$this->get('integration')`. Could you show full `services.yml` file? It should not tell that service does not exist if your definition is right.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, had changed the name of the service for some tests. If calling services from the container works. Thank you very much for everything. At one point I edit the question with the answer. Again, thank you very much everyone.